# Boost asio io_service vs io_context

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost asio library with c++. I found that io_service and io_context have similarities. for example both have method run and others. Could someone please detail differences between these two classes( like usage, conceptual idea, structural difference et.c)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use `io_context`, it replaces `io_service`.

According to boost issue [#110](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/issues/110):

> `io_service` is deprecated. Yes, you should use `io_context`. Beware that the "old" API is deprecated as well (e.g. `io_service.post()`, you should use `post(io_context, handler)`).
>
> . . .
>
> `io_service` -> `io_context`
> `io_service.post()` -> `io_context.get_executor().post()`
> `io_service.dispatch()` -> `io_context.get_executor().dispatch()`
>
> `io_service::strand` -> `strand<io_context::executor_type>`
>
> there were also changes to composed operation customization hooks -
> there are only 2 now - `boost::asio::associated_allocator` and
> `boost::asio::associated_executor`, which default to looking for
> `get_allocator()`, `get_executor()`, `T::allocator_type`, `T::executor_type`
> members of the composed operation function object.
>
> This is not a complete list.

These changes are related to [Networking TS compatibility](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html).

Seems to have been added in [Boost 1.66](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_12_0___boost_1_66).

Comment: Some documentation seems to be out of date as in the examples of `1.71` they are still using `io_service`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html