# Boost 1.71.0: How to get process output?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I had code like this that worked fine on `Ubuntu 18.04` and with `Boost 1.65.0`:

```
// See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html
std::pair<int, std::string> runCommandAndGetOutput(const std::string & cmd, const std::vector<std::string> & args)
{
  namespace bp = boost::process;
  boost::asio::io_service ios;
  std::future<std::string> data;
  bp::child c(cmd, bp::args(args), bp::std_in.close(), bp::std_out > data, bp::std_err > bp::null, ios);
  ios.run();
  if (c.exit_code()) {
    std::cerr << "Command '" << cmd << "' failed with return value: " << c.exit_code();
  }
  return { c.exit_code(), data.get() };
}
```

However, after upgrading to `Ubuntu 20.04` and `Boost 1.71.0` this doesn't compile anymore because it seems that `boost::asio::io_service` is deprecated and doesn't exist anymore.

After googling I realized that I must use `boost::asio::io_context` instead.

Ok:

```
std::pair<int, std::string> runCommandAndGetOutput(const std::string & cmd, const std::vector<std::string> & args)
{
  namespace bp = boost::process;
  boost::asio::io_context ioc;
  std::future<std::string> data;
  bp::child c(cmd, bp::args(args), bp::std_in.close(), bp::std_out > data, bp::std_err > bp::null, ioc);
  ioc.run();
  if (c.exit_code()) {
    std::cerr << "Command '" << cmd << "' failed with return value: " << c.exit_code();
  }
  return { c.exit_code(), data.get() };
}
```

This compiles, but just doesn't work. Trying to run e.g. `/usr/bin/free` returns exit code `383` that doesn't make any sense.

What makes this difficult is that the documentation of `Boost 1.71.0` is still using `io_service`:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html

Does anyone know how this should be done right?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753391/boost-asio-io-service-vs-io-context

Comment: That doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `wait` until the child is finished.

[`exit_code`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idm45477675646672-bb) - "*Get the exit_code. The return value is without any meaning if the child wasn't waited for or if it was terminated.*"

```
#include "boost/process.hpp"

#include <iostream>

std::pair<int, std::string> runCommandAndGetOutput(
    const std::string& cmd, const std::vector<std::string>& args) {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    std::future<std::string> data;
    bp::child c(cmd, bp::args(args), bp::std_in.close(), bp::std_out > data,
                bp::std_err > bp::null, ioc);
    ioc.run();
    
    c.wait();                        // <---- here

    if(c.exit_code()) {
        std::cerr << "Command '" << cmd
                  << "' failed with return value: " << c.exit_code();
    }
    return {c.exit_code(), data.get()};
}

int main() {
    auto rv = runCommandAndGetOutput("/usr/bin/free", {});

    std::cout << "\n----------\n" << rv.second << '\n' << rv.first << '\n';
}
```

Comment: There is no member `wait` in `boost::asio::io_context`.

Comment: @juzzlin It's not the context - it's the child (`c.wait();`). Just add the line I added and you'll see that it works fine. Fwiw - I also find the boost documentation regarding these things extremely hard to read especially since it's outdated.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll try that. Still note that the current documentation says: `Passing an instance of boost::asio::io_service to the launching function automatically cause it to wait asynchronously for the exit, so no call of wait is needed`. This is not cool.

Comment: The documentation is outdated - I find it very hard to learn boost by reading their documentation.